# React Native Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-dom

I'm programming with some friends a Chess App and now we get an Error implementing the Chess itself.
we get the error in the first const of the function as well as at the Export of App.jsx

Our GitHub Repo: [Chedu](https://github.com/Manubown/ChEdu)

App.jsx

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { gameSubject, initGame, resetGame } from "./Game";
import Board from "./Board";

function App() {
  const [board, setBoard] = useState([]); //get Error here
  const [isGameOver, setIsGameOver] = useState();
  const [result, setResult] = useState();
  const [turn, setTurn] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    initGame();
    const subscribe = gameSubject.subscribe((game) => {
      setBoard(game.board);
      setIsGameOver(game.isGameOver);
      setResult(game.result);
      setTurn(game.turn);
    });
    return () => subscribe.unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      {isGameOver && (
        <h2 className="vertical-text">
          GAME OVER
          <button onClick={resetGame}>
            <span className="vertical-text"> NEW GAME</span>
          </button>
        </h2>
      )}
      <div className="board-container">
        <Board board={board} turn={turn} />
      </div>
      {result && <p className="vertical-text">{result}</p>}
    </div>
  );
}
export default App(); //Error Anonymous Function
```

in Index.js we are Rendering the function and export it.

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import { DndProvider } from "react-dnd";
import { HTML5Backend } from "react-dnd-html5-backend";
export default ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <DndProvider backend={HTML5Backend}>
      <App />
    </DndProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

And at last we want to render the index.js in our ChessBoardPage

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Dimensions,
  Switch,
} from "react-native"; //components

import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import cheduLogo from "../Pictures/Logo.png";
import loginPictureBlack from "../Pictures/login.png";
import loginPictureWhite from "../Pictures/login_white.png";
import registerPictureBlack from "../Pictures/register.png";
import registerPictureWhite from "../Pictures/register_white.png";
import userPictureBlack from "../Pictures/user.png";
import userPictureWhite from "../Pictures/user_white.png";

import ChessGame from "./ChessBoard/index";

const windowWidth = Dimensions.get("window").width;
const windowHeight = Dimensions.get("window").height;

const { width } = Dimensions.get("window");

const x = 100;
const y = 200;

export default class TempPage extends React.Component {
  state = {
    switchValue: false,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    SwitchLogin: loginPictureBlack,
    SwitchRegister: registerPictureBlack,
    SwitchUser: userPictureBlack,
    SunMoon: "☀️",
    ShadowBackgroundColor: "white",
  };

  handleSwitchBackground = () => {
    [...]
    }
  };

  render() {
    let { backgroundColor } = this.state;
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          windowWidth,
          windowHeight,
          backgroundColor: this.state.backgroundColor,
        }}
      >
          
        [...]

        {/*Content*/}
        <View stlye={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <ChessGame />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
[...]
```

Comment: Minor typo `export default App` not `export default App()` - do not invoke the function

Answer (score 0):

sometime we have issues in react when using anonymous functions. Since anonymous functions aren’t assigned an identifier (via const/let/var), they aren’t persistent whenever this functional component inevitably gets rendered again. This causes JavaScript to allocate new memory each time this component is re-rendered instead of allocating a single piece of memory only once when using “named functions”
consider refactoring your code as follows

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { gameSubject, initGame, resetGame } from "./Game";
import Board from "./Board";

const App = () => {
  const [board, setBoard] = useState([]); //get Error here
  const [isGameOver, setIsGameOver] = useState();
  const [result, setResult] = useState();
  const [turn, setTurn] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    initGame();
    const subscribe = gameSubject.subscribe((game) => {
      setBoard(game.board);
      setIsGameOver(game.isGameOver);
      setResult(game.result);
      setTurn(game.turn);
    });
    return () => subscribe.unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      {isGameOver && (
        <h2 className="vertical-text">
          GAME OVER
          <button onClick={resetGame}>
            <span className="vertical-text"> NEW GAME</span>
          </button>
        </h2>
      )}
      <div className="board-container">
        <Board board={board} turn={turn} />
      </div>
      {result && <p className="vertical-text">{result}</p>}
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

I am not sure why  you are using HTML tags in react native, which think are not yet supported in  `App.jsx`. You should return a `<View/>` tag instead of div.